# RSS Feed Won't Load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rss

I have a tableview that shows data from an RSS feed and it works fine as long as it is not the root view of my app. I have always shown it by pressing a button but now I'm wanting to have it be the first view the user sees but the activity indicator just keeps spinning and the content never loads. Like I said, when I've pushed it onto the navigation stack from a button, it loads the content so I'm not really sure why it won't load when it's the first view shown.

AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     AgStoriesViewController *rootView = [[AgStoriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
        [rootView setWebViewController:wvc];

        KFBNavControllerViewController *navController = [[KFBNavControllerViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
        navController.delegate = rootView;
     self.window.rootViewController = navController;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

TableView with RSS

```
#import "AgStoriesViewController.h"
#import "RSSChannel.h"
#import "RSSItem.h"
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "DTCustomColoredAccessory.h"
#import "UIImage+ImageEffects.h"
#import "UIView+Borders.h"
#import "TSMessage.h"
#import "TSMessageView.h"
#import "ArticleCell.h"
#import "KFBAppDelegate.h"
#import "MenuTableViewController.h"

@implementation AgStoriesViewController
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
}

@synthesize webViewController, blurredView, contentView, menuShown;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.navigationController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    menuShown = NO;

    UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sunset"];
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:background];

    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;

    self.title = @"Ag News";

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        UIImage *hamburgerButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_button"];
        UIBarButtonItem *listButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:hamburgerButton style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = listButton;
    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width / 2, height / 2, 37, 37)];
        loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2 - 37);
    }
    else
    {
        loadingIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(142, 365, 37, 37)];
    }

    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.tableView addSubview:loadingIndicator];
    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)showMenu
{
    if (!menuShown)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

        UIColor *kfbBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:8.0/255.0f green:77.0/255.0f blue:139.0/255.0f alpha:1];

        contentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
        contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
        contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        blurredView = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
        [blurredView setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [blurredView setBarTintColor:kfbBlue];

        MenuTableViewController *menu = [[MenuTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuTableViewController" bundle:nil];
        menu.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight - 50);
        [self.view addSubview:contentView];
        [contentView addSubview:blurredView];
        [self addChildViewController:menu];
        [contentView addSubview:menu.view];
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        menuShown = YES;
    }
    else if (menuShown)
    {
        [contentView removeFromSuperview];
        [blurredView removeFromSuperview];
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        menuShown = NO;
    }
}

- (void)closeMenu
{
    [contentView removeFromSuperview];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"%@ found a %@ element", self, elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"channel"])
    {
        channel = [[RSSChannel alloc]init];

        [channel setParentParserDelegate:self];


        [parser setDelegate:channel];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"channel items %lu", (unsigned long)[[channel items]count]);
    return [[channel items]count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 215;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    RSSItem *item = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"articleCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *nibs =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ArticleCell" owner:self options:NULL];
        cell = [nibs firstObject];
    }
    cell.articleTitle.text = [item title];
    cell.articleDescription.text = [item infoString];

    cell.articleTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.articleDescription.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.articleTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:22.0];
    cell.articleDescription.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FranklinGothicStd-ExtraCond" size:16.0];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}

- (void)fetchEntries
{

    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kyfbnewsroom.com/category/ag-news/feed"];


    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self)
    {
        [self fetchEntries];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [xmlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{ 
    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

    UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sunset"];
    UIImage *effectImage = [background applyDarkEffect];
    UIImageView *blurredBackground = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    blurredBackground.image = effectImage;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = blurredBackground;

    // Create the parser object with the data received from the web service
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];

    // Give it a delegate
    [parser setDelegate:self];

    //Tell it to start parsing - the document will be parsed and the delegate of NSXMLParser will get all of its delegate messages sent to it before this line finishes execution - it is blocking
    [parser parse];

    // Get rid of the XML data as we no longer need it
    xmlData = nil;

    NSMutableArray *actionAlerts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (RSSItem *object in channel.items)
    {
        if (object.isActionAlert)
        {
            [actionAlerts addObject:object];
        }
    }

    for (RSSItem *object in actionAlerts)
    {
        [channel.items removeObject:object];
    }

    // Reload the table
    [[self tableView]reloadData];

    NSLog(@"%@\n %@\n %@\n", channel, [channel title], [channel infoString]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Release the connection object, we're done with it
    connection = nil;

    // Release the xmlData object, we're done with it
    xmlData = nil;

    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

    // Grab the description of the error object passed to us
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fetch failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];

    // Create and show an alert view with this error displayed
    // UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // [av show];

    [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:@"Network Error" subtitle:errorString type:TSMessageNotificationTypeError];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

        RSSItem *entry = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:req];
        webViewController.hackyURL = url;
    }
    else
    {
        [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

        NSMutableArray *details = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

        UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

        [details replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:detailNav];

        KFBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KFBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
        appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = webViewController;
        [appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];

        // Grab the selected item
        RSSItem *entry = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        // Construct a URL with the link string of the item
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

        // Construct a request object with that URL
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        // Load the request into the web view
        [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:req];
        webViewController.hackyURL = url;

        // Set the title of the web view controller's navigation item
        [[webViewController navigationItem]setTitle:[entry title]];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to reload your table data -

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
     [[self tableView]reloadData];
}
```

This method is called when parsing of your xml document is finished. You are reloading table when data is not properly set in array, so it is showing you empty table.

EDIT - 
Call connection method properly on view Initialization.

`fetchEntries` needs to be called in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: That method doesn't fix it. Plus, without this method it works just fine if I'm pushing the view controller onto the navigation stack

Comment: where are your tableview data source and delegate defined, it not that set those? Also have you put breakpoint at cellForRow method and checked what is the value of item there?

Comment: It looks like connectionDidFinishLoading never gets called since the loading indicator never stops spinning. I never had an issue with it until I made it the first view the app shows.

Comment: Have you checked whether fetchEntries method gets called or not?

Comment: fetchEntries does not get called either.

Comment: you need to move this method to viewDidLoad from init.

Comment: calling fetchEntries in viewDidLoad fixed it. Thanks!